# Google Analytics Data API (GA4) running on AWS Lambda Python Function Generate No module named 'google.rpc' Error

Tags: python, aws-lambda, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics
Following the "samples/snippets/run_report.py" python sample code in the above link, I try to run it on AWS Lambda with python3.8 x86_64

The dependencies are packaged with the code such as

- google_analytics_data-0.16.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- grpcio-1.51.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
- grpcio_tools-1.51.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
- google_api_core-2.11.0-py3-none-any.whl

However I still facing the error like this

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module  No module named 'google.rpc'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I've searched which lib contains 'google.rpc'
but with no luck

Would you please give some hints about this issue

Thank you sincerely
Have a good day

Comment: Did you create the Lambda Layer and attach to the function?

Comment: Yes! I do attach the layer to the function. Do you know which lib containing 'google.rpc' ?

Comment: I have not worked with grpc before, not sure about that